# How to use spotify api's in window 8 apps?

Tags: c#, windows-8, spotify

I want to create an app in window 8 using Spotify api's. I go through its document but it is not quite clear, how to use it. I want to use main basic features of spotify like music search, playlist access, playlist management, add songs to playlist. But I am not getting what spotify api's I should use for it.
  Can any one tell me how I can use spotify api's as free??

Answer (score 0):

[Libspotify SDK](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/libspotify/)

It doesn't have native C# or .NET support. You will need to use Interop.

As for licensing- read the Terms Of Use

```
The Libspotify SDK and CocoaLibSpotify are not intended for use in commercial 
applications or in conjunction with commercial hardware products.
```

Comment: It means I can't use spotify api in my window 8 app?? Or there is any way to use it?? I have Libspotify api but I think for it we need application key and for that I should have Premium account. But I want to use it as free. i want to create an app in winodw 8 in which user can get all basic functionalities of spotify...